google-chrome-extension and .env file
How to set environment variables and access to them? Similarly as we can do in normal application via 'process.env.' (process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL, process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY etc).
Thank you!
I saw in the StackOveflow the answer how define if it is 'development' mode. But didn't see the way to set the variables. I suppose it is possible to define the values in storage regarding to mode kind. But I wonder if it is possible to have '.env' file.

There's no way. These variables are substituted only during build (webpack, rollup, and so on).
